# Swift - NSDictionary multidimensional

Tags: arrays, swift, class, structure, nsdictionary

currently i am working on a class which initializes an multidimensional array:

```
class Manager {

    var data: Dictionary<String,NSDictionary>

    init(data: Dictionary<String,NSDictionary>) {

        func getApiData() {

            getApiDataResource() { responseObject, error in

                let resourceA = responseObject!

                self.data["resources"] = resourceA

            }

        }

    }  

}
```

The responseObject which is returned asyncronously has this structure:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            id: 1
            name: "Name1"
        },
        {
            id: 2
            name: "Name2"
        }
    ],
    "count": 2,
    "success": true
}
```

The structure i want to get in my "data"-variable:

```
{
    "resources": [
        {
            "resourceA":
                {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            id: 1
                            name: "Name1"
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2
                            name: "Name2"
                        }
                    ],
                    "count": 2,
                    "success": true
                }
        },
        {
            "resourceB": // and so on ...
        }
    ]
}
```

But when saving my responseObject into my "data"-variable:

```
self.data["resources"] = resourceAData // this line fails
```

It prints:

```
Cannot assign to the result of this expression
```

Anybody could help me with this problem??

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: You need to assign to resourceA, not resources.

Comment: corrected it, but this wasnt the bug :/

Comment: You are declaring the function `getApiData` inside the `init`. Is there a specific reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume there is a function defined as follow:

```
func getApiDataResource(callback: (responseObject:NSDictionary?, error:NSError?) -> ()) {
    // data retrieved from server at warp 8 here and other futuristic things
}
```

### Step 1 (required)

I moved the function `getApiData` outside the `init`.

```
class Manager {
    var data: Dictionary<String,NSDictionary>
    init(data: Dictionary<String,NSDictionary>) {
        getApiData()
    }
    func getApiData() {
        getApiDataResource() { responseObject, error in
            let resourceA = responseObject!
            self.data["resources"] = resourceA
        }
    }
}
```

Now the compiler is complaining about this:

> Use of `self` in method call `getApiData` before all store properties are initialized

and this

> Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
>   (As stated by you in a comment)
>   Fine. Let's fix it.

### Step 2  (required)

```
class Manager {

    var data: Dictionary<String,NSDictionary>

    init(data: Dictionary<String,NSDictionary>) {
        self.data = data
        getApiData()
    }

    func getApiData() {
        getApiDataResource() { responseObject, error in
            let resourceA = responseObject!
            self.data["resources"] = resourceA
        }
    }
}
```

Now it does compiles properly.

However I would adjust a couple of other things.

### Step 3 (suggested)

Inside the trailing closure you are using the `!`. You should avoid this when possible. And you are not checking the `error` parameter that could be not nil.

You should use `conditional unwrapping` that is a safe alternative to the `force unwrap` (you did with `!`).

```
class Manager {

    var data: Dictionary<String,NSDictionary>

    init(data: Dictionary<String,NSDictionary>) {
        self.data = data
        getApiData()
    }

    func getApiData() {
        getApiDataResource() { responseObject, error in
            if let resourceA = responseObject where error == nil {
                self.data["resources"] = resourceA
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the code does not crash if `responseObject` from the closure is `nil`.

### Step 4 (just a preference)

This is just a style preference.
Swift allows you to define your dictionary this way (as you did).

```
Dictionary<String,NSDictionary>
```

or this way:

```
[String:NSDictionary]
```

The 2 statement are equivalent. I just find more essential the second one. So...

```
class Manager {

    var data: [String:NSDictionary]

    init(data: [String:NSDictionary]) {
        self.data = data
        getApiData()
    }

    private func getApiData() {
        getApiDataResource() { responseObject, error in
            if let resourceA = responseObject where error == nil {
                self.data["resources"] = resourceA
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know is this is what you need!

Answer (score 0):

You have `let data: Dictionary<String, Array<String>>`, should be `var data: Dictionary<String, Array<String>>`

Comment: thanks for answer: but than it prints: "Cannot assign value of type 'NSDicitionary' to value of type 'Array<String>'"

Comment: Now you have a casting problem  what that is saying is you are passing in an NSDictionary,  and expecting it to go into an Array<String>

Comment: i am really not sure, hot to process it now, couldnt you help me?

Comment: `var data: Dictionary<String,NSDictionary>` is probably what you want,  why does it have to be Array<String>

Comment: thanks, but now the variable "self.data" is being used before even intitialized, is this because the data is retireved asyncronously?

Comment: I was just assuming code is missing because right now your code does nothing since the func is nested inside init,  you need to make it optional if you want to compile before initializing  `var data: Dictionary<String,NSDictionary>?`